# How do I block internet connections in dlink router?

Tags: wireless-router

How do you block a connection (for example, 38.99.106.17:80)?

[image]

I tried going into Advanced > Inbound filter and added an inbound filter rule but for some reason it does not work.

Comment: did you also block outbound?

Comment: what do you mean by "outbound"?

Comment: Look at the column headed "Dir" short for Direction. All those entires are "OUT" short for Outbound

Comment: yes, I blocked outbound